# How do I create a new collection?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a chat app where there are `GroupConversations` and `GroupMessages`. Following the example of some of the Firestore YouTube videos, I've chosen to structure my data this way:

The ID of the GroupConversation is the ID for the collection of GroupMessages associated with that GroupConversation. Then inside of that document should be a new collection called `Messages` which holds documents.

Does that make sense or am I overcomplicating things? I can't seem to create that `Messages` collection or set anything to it in my Swift code

```
GroupConversations
    id
    title
    desc
    memberIds

GroupMessages 
    GroupConversationID
        createdAt: Date // just because I need a key and a document?
        Messages (new collection)
            Message1
            Message2
            Message3
```

Thanks

Edit: Added Swift code

```
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        var data: [String: Any] = [
            "text": title,
            "senderUsername": username,
            "createdAt": Date(),
            "updatedAt": Date()
        ]

        let creationData: [String: Any] = [
            "text": "Group Created",
            "createdAt": Date()
        ]

        let doc = db.collection("GroupMessages").addDocument(data: creationData)
        db.document("GroupMessages/\(groupConvo.documentId)/\(doc.documentID)/messages").setData(data) { error in
            if error == nil {
                completion()
            }
        }
```

In my console, I'm seeing a new GroupMessage object created but not sub-collection of that GroupMessage called `messages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not building the path to the document correctly.  Document paths always alternate between collection and document names.  To build a path to a document in a subcollection, it would go collection/document/subcollection/document.  It looks like you've mixed up the last two elements in the string you're building.

In my opinion, it's harder to go wrong if you build up the document using methods rather than trying to build a string.  Something like this:

```
db
    .collection("GroupMessages")
    .document(groupConvo.documentId)
    .collection("Messages")
    .document(doc.documentId)
    .setData(...)
```

Comment: Ahhh, had those backwards. Yeah that build method is a lot better than my string gibberish. Thanks again Doug!